# Django forms - submitting the data isn't working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, crud

I'm really new to Django and I want to teach myself my making a simple note. But I don't understand how django forms work. I made simple template when I can display the user's notes and now I am trying to make a view when the user can add new notes to account using a simple form.

Here is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from .forms import CreateUserForm, CreateNoteForm


from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


from .models import *

# Create your views here.
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else: 
            messages.info(request, 'Username or pasword is incorrect')

    context = {}

    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', context)

def registerPage(request): 
    form = CreateUserForm()

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()
            user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for '+ user)
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request): 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        context = {'username': username}

        return render(request, 'accounts/home.html', context)


def notes(request):
    username = None 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.username
        user_id = request.user.pk

    user_notes = Note.objects.filter(user=user_id)

    context = {
        'user_notes': user_notes,
        'username': username,
        #'user_id' : user_id,
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/notes.html', context)

def createNote(request): 
    username = request.user.username
    user_id = request.user.pk

    user_notes = Note.objects.filter(user=user_id)

    form = CreateNoteForm()

    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = CreateNoteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()
            return redirect('notes')
    context = {'user_notes': user_notes, 'form': form}

    return render(request, 'accounts/create_note.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from .models import Note

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class CreateNoteForm(forms.ModelForm): 

    class Meta: 
        model = Note
        fields = ['user', 'title', 'text']
```

and create_note.html:

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <form action="{% url 'notes' %}" method="POST">
                <div class="card-body">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form}}
                    <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
                </div> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

The problem is the new note isn't added when I submit the data. And also if anyone have other suggestions for structuring my views or making this app better I am happy to read them and learn new ways of improving my project. Sorry for long post. I am really noob.

Comment: Where does `{% url 'notes' %}` pointing? it seems it will go to `notes` view instead of the `createNote` view.  Please check here `<form action="{% url 'notes' %}"` if it points to the correct url.

Comment: Wow. I changed it to {% url 'create_note' %} and it worked. Can you explain why it has to be the createNote view?

Comment: The form's `action` attribute tells the form where to submit the data, in your case, you need to submit it to `{% url 'create_note' %}`.

Comment: And how I make the user field in the form to be autocompleted with the user is logged in?